# How to calculate the bounds of a Path in Android without including the control points of Bezier curves?

Tags: android, svg, graphics

Android has a Path class with a method `computeBounds()`.

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Path#computeBounds(android.graphics.RectF,%20boolean)

However in the case of Bezier curve paths, the bounds include the control points of the curve.

This is not ideal because I just want to calculate the bounds of the actual shape created by the Bezier curve.

It seems that Skia (the underlying library used by Android) has a computeTightBounds method which does what I want but Android doesn't seem to expose it.

https://api.skia.org/classSkPath.html#a597c8fcc5e4750542e2688b057a14e9e

How would I calculate the bounds without include the control points?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to get it directly.

To get an high accuracy set of bounds, you would need to calculate it yourself, by stepping through the path segments and calculating the actual bounds of each bezier, line, arc, etc.  Unfortunately Android does not provide a way to step through the elements of a `Path` once it is created.  So if you need a high accuracy result, hopefully you know the make up of the path before you do.

However there is a way to get a result with configurable accuracy, using `PathMeasure`.
Try the following.  *This code has not been tested.*

```
void computeExactBounds(RectF bounds, Path path, int accuracy)
{
   bool first = true;

   // Make sure accuracy defaults to something reasonable
   if (accuracy < 2)
      accuracy = 100;

   PathMeasure pm = new PathMeasure(path, false);
   // Step through all the subpaths of this path
   while (nextContour())
   {
      float  pathLen = pm.getLength();

      // To compute the bounds, we calculate the position of 'accuracy'
      // number of positions along the path.  The higher that accuracy is,
      // the more accurate the result, but the longer it will take.
      // But note that, in some extreme cases, it is possible that the
      // real path bounds may be slightly larger than the bounds that
      // this method returns.
   
      float  pos = new float[];
      // Initialise bounds to the path start coordinates
      pm.getPosTan(0, pos, null);
      if (first) {
         bounds.set(pos[0], pos[1], pos[0], pos[1]);
         first = false;
      }
      else
         bounds.union(pos[0], pos[1]);

      // Step through 'accuracy' positions along the path,
      // making sure bounds includes all those positions
      for (int i=1; i <= accuracy; i++) {
         pm.getPosTan(pathLen * i / accuracy, pos, null);
         bounds.union(pos[0], pos[1]);
      }
   }
}
```

You could improve this code by using a binary search to adaptively split
the subpaths into smaller segments (rather than steeping along the path in small fixed increments).  This is what `path.approximate()`
does. See below.

---

If you are on API 26 and greater, you would be able to speed up this code by using `path.approximate()` to calculate the positions.

*This code hasn't been tested either :)*

```
void computeExactBounds(RectF bounds, Path path, float acceptableError)
{
   // A typical value of acceptableError might be 0.5. But if, say,
   // your path uses extremely small or large coordinate values, you
   // might need to adjust this.  Choose a value that works out as
   // equivalent to around half a pixel at the current scale;

   float[]  pos = path.approximate(acceptableError);
   for (int i = 0; i < pos.length; i += 3)
   {
      if (i == 0)
         bounds.set(pos[i+1], pos[i+2], pos[i+1], pos[i+2]);
      else
         bounds.union(pos[i+1], pos[i+2]);
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There isn't any direct way.
My solution is to update a RectF according to Bezier's End points during drawing.

```
final RectF mRect = new RectF(999999,999999,-1,-1);

public void updateBounds(final float endPointX, final float endPointY) {
    if (mRect.left == 999999) mRect.set(endPointX, endPointY, endPointX, endPointY);
    else mRect.union(endPointX, endPointY);
}
```

However this solution doesn't take in count StrokeWidth but only the virtual/invisible Path (which has "wideness" equal to Zero). So if your need is "*compute effective drawn path bounds*" you need to subtract/sum Half of "*Path.getStrokewidth()*" during bounds computation.

Comment: This won't compute a very good bounds.  It is highly likely to return bounds that are smaller than the path.

Comment: Of course my example has limitations, and in some cases this could compute wrong bounds...but for my needs it works well. You could improve this code in the case Control Points are OUTSIDE the previous computed bounds: in this case you can do a PathMeasure() and navigate to all segments by searching the most high/low/left/right. But I prefer to use approssimate bounds due to low CPU usage because until now I always used boundaries just for do drawBitmap(), and drawing 10% additional pixels (than the real required) wasn't a problem.